# displaying results from jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, cakephp-1.3

I have a cakephp app that delivers some results and a php file that nicely formats these
results as a table.

in my search page, i use jquery to invoke autocomplete on the cake app. everything is peachy up to this point. i can send in my request, ajax works, i get the formatted html page back. but since im a jquery newbie, i cant figure out how to actually display this result ..

my jquery is something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input#search").autocomplete(........
```

sorry dont have the exact codeblock, im at home now...

How do i display the html content i get back from ajax in a div using jquery's autocomplete?

thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try pass the returned html page content into a div object via "html".

```
$('#id-something').html(ajaxResultHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery autocomplete displays the  result in the matched element, in this case the input with the id `search`, but the response of the script must be in JSON notation, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a `string` as the source so in this case the URL you specify must return `JSON` data, it can't return `HTML`. The autocomplete dialog should generate automatically once you do that.

If you want to customize the dialog, you can overwrite `_renderMenu` and `_renderItem`. A good example of that is the comboxbox demo on the [jQuery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

If you really want to stick with `div` for the dialog, you'll need to overwrite a few functions since the usage of `ul` and `li` is hardcoded. If you decide to go this route, don't overwrite the jQuery UI files, extend it otherwise you'll have an update nightmare later on. See [Scott González's autocomplete html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js) to get started. Once you know how to extend it, you'll need to dig in `jquery.ui.autocomplete.js` and look for the `jQuery UI Menu` widget and depending on your modification you'll need to overwrite the `refresh`, `move`, `first` and `last` functions.

If all you want is to display what you selected into a `div`, you need to use the `select` method, this method is triggered when an element in the dialog is selected.

Hopefully this will help you get started.